# Create Inertia Link inside vue method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I need to generate an Intertia Link based on different conditions.

I have the following code in my template:

```
<td v-html="buildLink(data)"></td>
```

And the following code in the method section:

```
methods: {
 buildLink(data) {
    // Some logic here
       -----
    // And then Finally need to return the URL as intertia link
    return '<Link href="route(routeName)">data.title</Link>';    
 },
}
```

The output it produces is following

```
 <td data-v-5bd01d73="">
   <link href="http://project.test/dashboard">Home
 </td>
```

As you can see the above code does not generate the Inertia JS anchor tag. I know I could get the desired result using conditional rendering in the template section, but I am looking for a solution to generate the link inside the method.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Struggling with the exact same problem.

Comment: @oliverbj Yes, I have managed to get the result but with a different approach. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the result with a different approach. Here's how I did it:

```
<td><Link :href="getLink(data)">{{ data.title }}</Link></td>
```

And the following code in the method section:

```
methods: {
 getLink(data) {             
    // Some logic here
    if(data.is_customer)
    {
      return 'http://example.com/customer-route-url';
    }
    else {
      return 'http://example.com/admin-route-url';
    }
 },
}
```